# How to encode multiple videos parallel (Debian)

Tags: encoding, parallel-processing, debian, mp4, x264

I'd like to encode some video files either to **MP4** and **X264** format in Linux Debian.

It is very important that I encode multiple files parallel. 
E.g. I want to encode two videos parallel on a Dual Code Machine and put the other videos in a queue. When a Video is finished I want the free core to encode the next video in the queue. Also even when this'd work with x264 I don't know about MP4.

What is the best approach here?
x264 supports parallel encoding but I don't know whether this is parallel encoding for multiple files or parallel encodings of different version for one single video.
Is there a way I can assign a encoding-process to core1 and another to core2?

Sincerly,
wolfen

Comment: What programming language? I'd be inclined to use a make file and process the videos with `make -j2`. I wouldn't touch processor affinity though. The OS's scheduler can probably make a better call on that one than most users/developers.

Comment: Either C++ or java, doesn't matter. This is a parallel programming experiment thats why I want to go this way.

Comment: @Wolfen: (1) What have you tried? (2) is this homework by chance? if so - retag.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to encode multiple videos in parallel (are they racing?), or just not leave extra processor cores idle?

In either case, [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) should work for your needs.

By default FFmpeg will use all available CPUs for any processing, allowing faster processing of single videos.  However, you can also explicitly specify the number of cores to use via the `-threads` parameter, e.g., `ffmpeg -i input.mov -threads 1 output.mov` will only use one core.

It doesn't have any built-in queueing, though, you'll still have to code that aspect on your own.